# PropType is defined but never used eslint error

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

When using predefined constant SHAPE for object which is straight destructured i get eslint error, `react/no-unused-proptypes`.

f.e.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const View = ({
    foo: {
        bar,
    },
}) => (
    <div>{ bar }</div>
);

const PREDEFINED_SHAPE = PropTypes.shape({
    bar: PropTypes.string,
});

View.propTypes = {
    foo: PREDEFINED_SHAPE.isRequired,
};

/*
 * When predefined shape is not used, the error dissapears
 * f.e.
 * *

View.propTypes = {
    foo: PropTypes.shape({
        bar: PropTypes.string,
    }).isRequired,
};

*/

export default View;
```

Why is the first way not allowed or is it just some bug with eslint?

i'm using eslint versions:

- "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
- "eslint": "^4.19.1",
- "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
- "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.8.4",
- "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
- "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.3.0",
- "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
- "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",

Comment: This is normal, since your component is not consuming foo prop, but bar. This is why eslint is complaining

Comment: @LazarNikolic but why isn't it complaining when prop-type is not predefined though? See commented code

Comment: @LazarNikolic and isn't propTypes purpose to define what propTypes component receives? So even if component is not consuming `foo` prop it still should be defined?